# Programmatically call storyboard in delegate

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, uiviewcontroller, uistoryboard

I'm trying to programmatically call my storyboard.
My storyboard consists of the following:

[Navigation Controller] -> [MainMenuView] -> [DetailsView]

The "MainMenu" identifier was placed in the [MainMenuView]

The problem i'm having is the screen showing blank. What do i need to do?

Thanks.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{       
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];

    MainMenuView *rootViewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MainMenu"];

    return YES
}
```

Answer (score 16):

You need to first create the window manually and then add the rootViewController in it (the previous answer was almost correct):

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];

    UIViewController *mainViewController = [storyboard instantiateInitialViewController];

    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    self.window.rootViewController = mainViewController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}
```

Comment: This is no longer true for ios 9

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the rootViewController property of your application's window:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{       
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
    MainMenuView *rootViewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MainMenu"];

    self.window.rootViewController = rootViewController;

    return YES;
}
```

Comment: I have set it but it still blank

Comment: @RockBaby: The AppDelegate's `window` property isn't set up yet, you're messaging nil. Do this first in didFinish...: `self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];`